# Squealing brakes on 14 ' Audi S4 (B8.5)

Tags: brakes, noise, audi

I have a 2014 Audi s4 (B8.5) that has around 35,000 km and the brakes are already squealing when I slow down by braking gradually.

The sound is intense, and very annoying. It comes and goes but for the most part it's always there. Can something like that be enforced to be fixed by the manufacturer? The car is under a 4-year warranty. I should also mention that I brake very gradually by nature but I believe that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Were the brakes wet (i.e. driving in the rain), or does this also happen in the dry?

Comment: Its constant under any conditions

Comment: Do you happen to know if you have carbon-metalic brake pads?

Comment: I will call dealer on Monday to find out.

Comment: @eYe Just wondering what was the reason behind the noise if you could share? I am having same issue.

Comment: @Tan the reason turned out to be simply combination of brakes dust and wear that was caused by my "slow braker" technique. Once I replaced my brake pads with the ceramic ones, I haven't heard a single squeal! However, keep in mind that the brake feeling will change a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Carbon-metallic Brake Pads

If you do have carbon-metallic brake pads, especially high performance ones like you might find on an Audi S4 (although I can't say for sure), the material that they are made out of do tend to be prone to noise which is an artifact that occurs from the manufacturer trying to optimise for braking efficiency.

### How to Fix Brake Noise

Here is a quote from [a website](https://mobiloil.com/en/article/car-maintenance/advanced-car-maintenance-tips/dealing-with-car-brake-noise) that you may find useful:

> If the noise pops up just before your vehicle comes to a complete stop, as opposed to squealing throughout the entire range of braking, the cause could be a brake pad that is vibrating against the rotor. A set of brake pad vibration damper pads could cure the squeal, but there's no guarantee.

You did say that `it comes and goes`, but you also said that for the most part `its always there` so I don't know if new brake pad vibration damper pads are going to fix your particular issue but it is definitely something to consider.

Another thing to consider would be to replace your brake pads altogether, which may be expensive and doesn't guarantee that it will fix your issue. Also I suspect that it would void your warranty, which on such a new, heavily depreciating car like yours you probably want to do!

Otherwise, the only thing I can suggest is taking it back to the dealer to see what they say. Especially if it is happening all the time, not just when you come to a stop.

*Note:* If you have a rather sporty driving style or you go for a track day, your brake temperatures can get hot. It is normal if the brakes produce noise at this point. Just stop and let them cool down for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some copper grease **between brake piston and pad**.
Not between pads and disc, or it will just ruin your discs away...